# how to navigate to a directory in linux?

Tags: linux

I downloaded `ndk` and then uncompressed it. How to change to that directory in linux?

This is my directory: `/home/embdes/projects/android1/android-ndk-r5/`

When I enter that into the terminal I get: `android-ndk-r5: is a directory`

Comment: what does android have to do with it?

Comment: Remove the Android tag and add Linux tag

Comment: I am really not sure what you're asking, but I edited your question to make it say what I think you're trying to say here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm I am not sure if you mean.. 
To RENAME a directory:

```
mv old_directory_name new_directory_name
```

To MOVE to a new directory:

```
cd path_to_new_directory
```

Comment: I *think* the OP is asking how to change his working directory, which he'll use `cd` for.